# Prove a neighborhood is can be obtained for all numbers on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Okay, for Example (a), first if we choose $\epsilon = a \implies a < 1-a = 1-\epsilon \implies a + \epsilon < 1$. Which satisfies the right side of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood definition. But I'm confused about the left side of the neighborhood because $\epsilon = a \implies 0 \leq a - \epsilon$. Combining the inequalities we have

$$ 0 \leq a - \epsilon < a < a + \epsilon < 1$$

I'm not sure how to say that the left part is in $U$ because $U$ doesn't include zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have $0 \in U$, in the definition of $\epsilon$-neighborhood you have $<$ not $\le$, so in that case the $\epsilon$-neighborhood would be $V_\epsilon(a)= \{x \in \mathbb R : |x-a|<a\}=(0,2a)$ since $a<0.5$ (otherwise $1-a<a$) we have that $(0,2a)\subseteq (0,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand your thinking. How do you take $a < 1/2$ to imply $0 < a - \epsilon < a < a + \epsilon < 1$ which is equivalent to $ 0 < 0 < a < 2a < 1$ ?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I think I didn't quite understand the definition.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is the smallest between $a$ and $1-a$. In this case the smallest of the two is $a$, so we have $a<1-a \; \rightarrow a<0.5$ but $a \in U$ so $0<a<0.5$. If it is still unclear just try an example on a paper. Draw $U$ and take $a=0.4,a=0.5,a=0.6$ (so that $\varepsilon$ would be $0.4,0.5,0.4$ and see what you obtain.